# Is there a way to insert the same row values in a temp table? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table #t that has a column already called ID with about 75 values. I've inserted another column called status and I want all of the values in the 'status' column to equal "A". Is there a way I can do this without having to manually insert A for each row?

Would want it to look like this but for all 75 rows

```
|ID|   |Status|
----------------
|24|   |  A   |
```

Comment: `UPDATE #t SET [Status] = 'A';`?

Comment: Best option is do this as you create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but you could do it with something like

```
update #t set Status = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the default value for status column.

```
Create table #test(id int, status varchar(1) default 'A');
insert into #test (id) values (1),(2),(3);

Select * From #test;

id  status
1   A
2   A
3   A
```

If your table is already created you may set the default value as the following:

```
ALTER TABLE #test ADD CONSTRAINT df_val DEFAULT 'A' FOR status;
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=218645d213747ecaa5a8c7ec19606f3b).

Comment: The table already exists, so you would need to do this in an `ALTER TABLE`